# How to see Partitions created in SSMS on a table & use them in SSAS to process the Model

Tags: sql-server, ssas, partition

I have HUGE table 300 M rows. I have created partition on table based on date in SSMS(sql server) using Partition wizard, then built Model in SSAS on TOP of this table. Want to use these partitions created to process the Model built in SSAS.

Can this be done? How to do it please guide?

NOte: I have tried to create partition in SSAS but that is not the route I want to take at this moment. If above works I want to explore further.

Answer (score 2):

Partitioning in table is different concept than partitioning in SSAS.

When you partition a table, you improve the performance on T-SQL querying.

When you partition on SSAS cube (Tabular or UDM), you get the benefit of partial processing like Monthly processing or Daily processing or generally processing based on some criteria. It allows you to process the cube based on specific criteria (or new data) instead of processing the whole.

The partitioning in SSAS is comprehensive process and I can't answer here. Please refer to below links to see how to partition your data in SSAS

[Partitioning in UDM Cubes](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-partition-an-ssas-cube-in-analysis-services-multidimensional/)

[Partitioning in Tabular Cube](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4874/how-to-partition-data-in-tabular-ssas/)